# How to connect SQLAlchemy to a GCP CLoud SQL instance using SSL?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to connect to a GCP Cloud SQL Instance using Python 3 and do not want to use the cloud proxy, I just want to connect directly using SSL certs so I followed the GCP guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#appaccessIP) to connect from a public IP secured with ssl keys.

Using this works for the mysql client:

```
mysql -uroot -pMyPassWord -h 1.2.3.4 --ssl-ca=server-ca.pem --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem --ssl-key=client-key.pem
```

But when I do what I believe is the same in Python I get an error:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_connect_string='mysql+mysqldb://root:MyPassWord@1.2.3.4:3306/mydb'
ssl_args = {'ssl': {'ssl_cert':'./client-cert.pem', 'ssl_key':'./client-key.pem', 'ssl_ca':'./server-ca.pem'}}
engine = create_engine(db_connect_string, connect_args=ssl_args)

print(engine.table_names())
```

The error is:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:
>   (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user
>   'root'@'1.2.3.4' (using password: YES)") (Background on this error at:
>   http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Which is straight forward enough if it wasn't for the fact that I:

1. Have already added my public IP address 1.2.3.4/32 as an authorised network.
2. I can access via mysql client so why does the restriction not apply there?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK finally got this working.  The error message is misleading as you'd expect it to be related to whitelisting my IP but it's not.  Here is the working code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

db_connect_string='mysql+mysqldb://root:MyPassWord@1.2.3.4:3306/mydb'
ssl_args = {'ssl': {'cert':'./client-cert.pem', 'key':'./client-key.pem', 'ca':'./server-ca.pem'}}
engine = create_engine(db_connect_string, connect_args=ssl_args)

print(engine.table_names())
```

The mysqlclient needs a dictionary called ssl with key pairs but all other answers I could find on stack had either the wrong ones or maybe they've been changed.

Here's the link to the dictionary required to pass as an argument:

https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#installation

Here is the MySQL documentation which explains the arguments:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-ssl-set.html

Full list of arguments here:

- mysql: The connection handler returned from mysql_init().
- key: The path name of the client private key file.
- cert: The path name of the client public key certificate file.
- ca: The path name of the Certificate Authority (CA) certificate file.
  This option, if used, must specify the same certificate used by the
  server.
- capath: The path name of the directory that contains trusted SSL CA
  certificate files.
- cipher: The list of permissible ciphers for SSL encryption.